# A program that takes two strings from user and arrange them alphabetically without using arrays and loops in java

Tags: java, sorting, alphabetical

Here is what i have done.I Need corrections in my code. Unable to understand why this isn't working.

```
public class NewClass2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name of first city: ");
    String s1 = obj.next();
    char x = s1.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter name of second city: ");
    String s2 = obj.next();
    char y = s1.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter name of third city: ");
    String s3 = obj.next();
    char z = s1.charAt(0);
    if (x<y && y<z)
    System.out.println("The three cities in alphabetical order are " + s1 + " "+ s2 + " " + s3);
    else if (y<x && x<z)
     System.out.println("The three cities in alphabetical order are " + s2+ " " + s1 + " " + s3);
    else if(z<x && x<y)
     System.out.println("The three cities in alphabetical order are " + s3 + " " + s1 + " " + s2);    
    else if (y<z && z<x)
     System.out.println("The three cities in alphabetical order are " + s2 + " " + s3 + " " + s1);
     else if (x<z && z<y)
     System.out.println("The three cities in alphabetical order are " + s1 + " " + s3 + " " + s2);
     else 
     System.out.println("The three cities in alphabetical order are " + s3 + " " + s2 + " " + s1);

}
}
```

Hoping to get the required solution.

Comment: `"Unable to understand why this isn't working."` - Then this is a good opportunity to learn how to solve problems.  Start by describing why you *think* it's not working.  What is it doing?  What do you expect it to be doing?  Why?  This is also a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using a debugger, step through the code line by line as it executes.  Observe the runtime values and behaviors.  Where does it differ from what you expect?  Why?

Comment: Hoping to get the required solution.  ..... WOW ..Please frame question correctly

Comment: Thanks anyway! I have got the answer to my problem by someone who was able to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You always compare the first input with itself!

```
char y = s1.charAt(0);
```

should be

```
char y = s2.charAt(0);
```

and

```
char z = s1.charAt(0);
```

should be

```
char z = s3.charAt(0);
```

Using a debugger can help you to understand such problems.

Comment: Thanks alot Man! Haha, I'm literally laughing at my mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Java's in-build method to do the sorting work for you. 
You could simply add these Strings to a list and call Collections.sort function.

Here is a working code for it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name of first city: ");
        String s1 = obj.next();
        list.add(s1);
        System.out.println("Enter name of second city: ");
        String s2 = obj.next();
        list.add(s2);
        System.out.println("Enter name of third city: ");
        String s3 = obj.next();
        list.add(s3);

        Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        System.out.println("The three cities in alphabetical order are - " + list);
    }

}
```